# panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to unpinned Go pointer (in Go Vulkan While Creating a Swapchain)

Tags: go, vulkan

I am Creating a swapchain in go vulkan im not sure why the above error is occuring below is the piece of code the error occur in vulkan CreateSwapchain function updated the code  .. new here ..
i am trying to solve this for long time using go-vulkan quering for swapchain support in above function and then using it but the above error is occuring

Side Function

```
func (p *Engine) QuerySwapchainSupport() SwapchainSupport {
    var sCapabilities vk.SurfaceCapabilities
    result := vk.GetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilities(p.PhysicalDevice, p.Surface, &sCapabilities)
    if result != vk.Success {
        panic(handleVkError(result))
    }

    var pSurfaceFormatCount uint32
    result = vk.GetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormats(p.PhysicalDevice, p.Surface, &pSurfaceFormatCount, nil)
    if result != vk.Success {
        panic(handleVkError(result))
    }
    surfaceFormat := make([]vk.SurfaceFormat, pSurfaceFormatCount)
    result = vk.GetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormats(p.PhysicalDevice, p.Surface, &pSurfaceFormatCount, surfaceFormat)
    if result != vk.Success {
        panic(handleVkError(result))
    }
    fmt.Println("Surface Formats:")

    var pSurfaceOresentCount uint32
    result = vk.GetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModes(p.PhysicalDevice, p.Surface, &pSurfaceOresentCount, nil)
    if result != vk.Success {
        panic(handleVkError(result))
    }
    presentMode := make([]vk.PresentMode, pSurfaceFormatCount)
    result = vk.GetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModes(p.PhysicalDevice, p.Surface, &pSurfaceFormatCount, presentMode)
    if result != vk.Success {
        panic(handleVkError(result))
    }

    var support SwapchainSupport
    support.sCapabilities = sCapabilities
    support.surfaceFormat = surfaceFormat
    support.presentMode = presentMode
    return support

}
```

Main Function

```
func (p *Engine) CreateSwapchain() {
    swapchainSupport := p.QuerySwapchainSupport()
    for _, avilableFormat := range swapchainSupport.surfaceFormat {
        avilableFormat.Deref()
        if avilableFormat.Format == vk.Format(vk.FormatB8g8r8a8Srgb) && avilableFormat.ColorSpace == vk.ColorSpace(vk.ColorspaceSrgbNonlinear) {
            p.SurfaceFrormat = avilableFormat
        }
    }

    for _, present := range swapchainSupport.presentMode {
        if present == vk.PresentMode(vk.PresentModeFifo) {
            p.PresentMode = present
        }
    }
    if swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.CurrentExtent.Width != vk.MaxUint32 {
        swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.CurrentExtent.Deref()
        p.Extend = swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.CurrentExtent
    } else {
        swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MinImageExtent.Deref()
        swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MaxImageExtent.Deref()

        actualExtend := &vk.Extent2D{
            Width:  uint32(p.width),
            Height: uint32(p.Height),
        }
        actualExtend.Width = maxUint32(swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MinImageExtent.Width, minUint32(swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MaxImageExtent.Width, actualExtend.Width))
        actualExtend.Width = maxUint32(swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MinImageExtent.Height, minUint32(swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MaxImageExtent.Height, actualExtend.Height))
        p.Extend = *actualExtend
    }
    var imageCount uint32
    swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.Deref()
    minImageCount := swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MinImageCount + 1
    if swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MaxImageCount > 0 && minImageCount > swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MaxImageCount {
        imageCount = swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.MaxImageCount
    } else {
        imageCount = minImageCount
    }

    createInfo := vk.SwapchainCreateInfo{
        SType:            vk.StructureTypeSwapchainCreateInfo,
        Surface:          vk.Surface(p.Surface),
        MinImageCount:    imageCount,
        ImageFormat:      p.SurfaceFrormat.Format,
        ImageColorSpace:  p.SurfaceFrormat.ColorSpace,
        ImageExtent:      p.Extend,
        ImageArrayLayers: 1,
        ImageUsage:       vk.ImageUsageFlags(vk.ImageUsageColorAttachmentBit),
    }

    indices := p.findQueueFamily()
    var queuefamilyIndices []uint32
    queuefamilyIndices = append(queuefamilyIndices, *indices.graphicsFamily)
    queuefamilyIndices = append(queuefamilyIndices, *indices.presentFamily)
    if *indices.presentFamily != *indices.graphicsFamily {
        createInfo.ImageSharingMode = vk.SharingMode(vk.SharingModeConcurrent)
        createInfo.QueueFamilyIndexCount = 1
        createInfo.PQueueFamilyIndices = queuefamilyIndices
    } else {
        createInfo.ImageSharingMode = vk.SharingMode(vk.SharingModeExclusive)
    }
    createInfo.PreTransform = swapchainSupport.sCapabilities.CurrentTransform
    createInfo.CompositeAlpha = vk.CompositeAlphaFlagBits(vk.CompositeAlphaOpaqueBit)
    createInfo.PresentMode = p.PresentMode
    createInfo.Clipped = vk.True

    ***
here is the error 
> result := vk.CreateSwapchain(p.LogicalDevice, &createInfo, nil,
> &p.Swapchain)

***
    if result != vk.Success {
        panic(handleVkError(result))
    }
    var swapchainImageCount uint32
    vk.GetSwapchainImages(p.LogicalDevice, p.Swapchain, &swapchainImageCount, nil)

    pSwapchainImages := make([]vk.Image, swapchainImageCount)
    vk.GetSwapchainImages(p.LogicalDevice, p.Swapchain, &swapchainImageCount, pSwapchainImages)
    p.SwapchainFrame = make([]SwapchainFrame, swapchainImageCount)
    for i := 0; i < int(swapchainImageCount); i++ {
        createInfo := vk.ImageViewCreateInfo{}
        createInfo.Image = pSwapchainImages[i]
        createInfo.ViewType = vk.ImageViewType(vk.ImageViewType2d)
        createInfo.Components.R = vk.ComponentSwizzle(vk.ComponentSwizzleIdentity)
        createInfo.Components.G = vk.ComponentSwizzle(vk.ComponentSwizzleIdentity)
        createInfo.Components.B = vk.ComponentSwizzle(vk.ComponentSwizzleIdentity)
        createInfo.Components.A = vk.ComponentSwizzle(vk.ComponentSwizzleIdentity)
        createInfo.Format = p.SurfaceFrormat.Format
        createInfo.SubresourceRange.AspectMask = vk.ImageAspectFlags(vk.ImageAspectColorBit)
        createInfo.SubresourceRange.BaseMipLevel = 0
        createInfo.SubresourceRange.LevelCount = 1
        createInfo.SubresourceRange.BaseArrayLayer = 0
        createInfo.SubresourceRange.LayerCount = 1
        result := vk.CreateImageView(p.LogicalDevice, &createInfo, nil, &p.SwapchainFrame[i].ImageView)
        if result != vk.Success {
            panic(handleVkError(result))
        }
        p.SwapchainFrame[i].Image = pSwapchainImages[i]
    }
}
```

Here is the Error

```
result := vk.CreateSwapchain(p.LogicalDevice, &createInfo, nil,
&p.Swapchain)
```

I tried Free() Deref() on the createinfo struct its not working Note i am not using New() anywhere
this is happening in go-Vulkan

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question needs a fully runnable, [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise it might be a better fit as an issue against the library you're using instead.

Comment: Hai i updated the code while creating swapchain the error is occuring i am guessing the error is because of dref() and Ref() of cgo but i am not able to figure out how to solve it i have marked where the error is occuring with this ***  .. new here actually dont know why so many down votes

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wrapping vulkan with go?  Any language with garbage collection seems a poor choice for this scenario.

Comment: I have Created a vulkan  renderer in c++ but for job i wanted to learn golang  and  so this was a side project got stuck in this error . go vulkan uses c in background so its just wrapper aroung c code